# R: Rprofile updated when new R version installed

Tags: r, startup, rprofile

When I installed a new version of R, my customised`.Rprofile` is not loaded. The R GUI starts using the new version and its corresponding `.Rprofile`.

Is there a way to still using the customised regardless of any update in the R version? A follow up question would be, can an R package load a different `.Rprofile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the help page `?.Rprofile`

To summarise:

1. R first checks for a site-wide configuration file. To find that file, run

   ```
   (site_path = R.home(component = "home"))
   fname = file.path(site_path, "Rprofile.site")
   file.exists(fname)
   ```
2. Then looks for `.Rprofile` in your current working directory - `getwd()`

   ```
   fname = file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile")
   file.exists(fname)
   ```
3. Then looks for an `.Rprofile` in your home area.

   ```
   file.exists("~/.Rprofile")
   ```

If you have an `.Rprofile` in you current working directory, R won't use the file in you home area.

---

Regarding your follow-up question. The `.Rprofile` is just an R file, so can be loaded via `source` and hence in a package. However, this is non-standard and should be avoided.

Comment: thanks for your reply. True illustrative. so what you are saying is that -unless you change the configuration file- you will always need to create a new personalized Rprofile.

Comment: When you say personalised, do you mean an Rprofile in your working directory

Comment: no. I mean one that i include code so it automatically load packages that i tend to use always.

Comment: Don't put that in your .Rprofile. It makes you code non-portable.

Comment: Why? http://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/ is nice. Your answer continues being no, right?

Comment: In the Rprofile you link to, there are no `library` or `require` calls, i.e. no packages are loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109683/discussion-between-donpresente-and-csgillespie).